# How to perform this task in 1 single, efficient mysql query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a list of TV shows stored in 1 table. Another table stores show genres (action, romance, comedy).

Most shows usually have more than 1 genre, so having a single tv_genre column and putting the genre ID in there isn't an option.

I could create a look up table which would store tv show id + genre id, and I could insert 1 row for every genre associated with the show.

Where things get fuzzy for me is when I want to output a list of shows on the index, and genre names associated with the tv show. How would I tie the 3 tables together into 1 efficient query (instead of running a separate query for each item on index, getting its genres).

For the purposes of this post, the tables are as follows

```
TV Show Table
- tv_id
- tv_name

Genre Table
- genre_id
- genre_name
```

Thanks!

Comment: you sure that's the entire table structure? because there's no relation between the two..

Comment: @orlandu63: He mentions in the question another table (he calls it a lookup table) to connect those two.

Answer (score 6):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

JOIN is the heart of SQL. you'll wind up with something like

```
select tv_name, genre_name
from tvshows
   left join shows_genres on tvshows.tv_id = shows_genres.tv_id
   left join genres on genres.genre_id = shows_genres.genre_id
```

Comment: You'll wind up with a show vanishing if it doesn't have any genres; you probably want left join.

Comment: @derobert: good point. What is proper SO-etiquette here, editing my answer or voting up yours?

Comment: actually, i guess the group_concat is worth the vote regardless :)

Comment: This will only work if there is one genre per show.... how do you get it to show multiple genres?

Answer (score 4):

You can use MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT function:

```
SELECT
    t.tv_name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.genre_name)
  FROM
    tv_shows t
    LEFT JOIN show_genres sg ON (t.tv_id = sg.tv_id)
    LEFT JOIN genres g ON (sg.genre_id = g.genre_id)
  WHERE
    /* whatever */
  GROUP BY t.tv_name
```

Your index page won't be particularly efficient; it can't be: you're pulling the entire table (well, all three tables). If it ever becomes a problem, look into caching.

Comment: Thats exactly how I do it... and its causing load problems for me. Remvoing group_concat statement cuts execution time from 1 second, to 0.1

Comment: The alternative is not to do the group_concat, and do it in your application (you'll get back one row per show/genre pair). Or, just cache it. How important is it that an index be completely current, is 1 hour old OK?

Comment: Caching would be very difficult to implement, since there are about 7 sorting methods, and about 1200 pages worth of content.

Answer (score 0):

Show-Genre Table
 - rv_id int
 - genre_id int

```
 select tv_show.name, genre.genre_name from tv_show,genre, show_genre where 
show_genre.tv_id = tv_show.tv_id and genre.genre_id=show_genre.genre_id
```

Something like this

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best sql but my idea was

```
select tv_name, genre_name
from tv_table, genre_table, lookup_table
where
    tv_table.tv_name = "superman"
    and
    tv_table.tv_id = lookup_table.tv_id
    and
    lookup_table.genre_id = genre_table.genre_id
```